# Running the following SAS code and would like to change the proc freq

Tags: sas, sas-macro

```
%_pd_prov_sched_future (
          _begin_date             = '01MAY2020'D
        , _end_date               = '31MAY2020'D
        , _fac_id                 = 
        , _parrs_clinic_cd        = 
        , _resource_id_schedule   =
        , _current_bkbl_nonbkbl_type =
        , _appt_avail_bkg            =
        , _add_bkd_appt_detail    = YES
        , _output_dataset         = _pd_prov_sched_future
        , _library                = work
                    ) ;
proc freq data=_pd_prov_sched_future;
    table PRIMARY_MNEMONIC_SCHEDULE*current_activity_cd*current_bkbl_nonbkbl_type/list;
run;
```

the proc freq looks like this[enter image description here]
I'm wondering how I can change the frequency & percent to select categories opposed to having it be the total.

Comment: This is a knowledge database, not a help desk. 
Could you state your problem in a more generic way?

Comment: And add the image properly

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read **[how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)** to let us help you better 

Answer (score 0):

Might be that you want to use a `BY` statement.

```
proc freq data=_pd_prov_sched_future;
  by category;
  table 
    PRIMARY_MNEMONIC_SCHEDULE
    * current_activity_cd
      * current_bkbl_nonbkbl_type / list;
run;
```